# Normal real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Q: Is there a **normal**, **real** matrix, which it's characteristic polynomial is $t(t-1)(t^2+1)$ ?

I think that there isn't such matrix, and I prove it by: if a matrix is real than it's diagonalizable, but the characteristic polynomial doesn't have real factors, meaning it is not diagonalizable.

am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
  0 & -1 &  0 & 0 \\
  0 &  0 &  0 & 1 \\
  0 &  0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It's characteristic polynomial is $t(t-1)(t^2+1)$, and you can verify that its normal.

The reason why your answer isn't right is that not every matrix which is real is diagonalizable.

Consider

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then all of its eigenvalues are zero, but there is no basis for which its diagonalizable. If you want to know more about normal matrices, consider looking up complex spectral theorem for finite dimensional operators.